# how can i get list of all partition with K dimension R

Tags: r, rstudio, partitioning, partition

i'm using this code:

```
library("partitions")
x <- c(2,4,6)       
parts <- listParts(length(x))
out <- rapply(parts, function(ii) x[ii], how="replace")
```

to calculate list vector of all partition, but i would be like list of partition with k dimension, for example:

```
k=2
{(2),(4,6)}{(4),(2,6)}{(6),(2,4)}
```

Comment: `listParts` comes from what package? Please edit the question with a call to `library(pkgname)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better ways of doing this but the following does what you want.

```
library(partitions)

funParts <- function(x, k){
  parts <- listParts(length(x))
  res <- lapply(parts, function(inx) sapply(inx, function(i) x[i]))
  res <- unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)
  res <- res[sapply(res, length) <= k]
  unique(res)
}

x <- c(2,4,6)       
k <- 2

funParts(x, 2)
funParts(x, 1)
funParts(4:10, 3)
```

Comment: ,this function retrun all set with max length k, but i would have in output a list of vector or similar structure that return a partition set for example :                                       
 {(2),(4,6)}{(2,4),(6)}{(6),(2,4)} {(2,4,6)}                                                                   where {(2),(4,6)} and {(2,4),(6)} are different set, most important thing is that i can identify and use  each partition set with k element